# unable to build in corda using gradlew command via terminal

Tags: java, corda

I'm an newbie in corda and I'm trying to follow the docs that are available. I'm trying to follow HelloWorld tutorial, and while trying to run `gradlew clean deployNodes` I'm getting the failure notification which is followed by this given below. I couldn't get a sense of what it's about.

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'cordapp-template-java'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordapp:3.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordapp:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/corda/plug
ins/cordapp/3.1.0/cordapp-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/corda/plugins/c
ordapp/3.1.0/cordapp-3.1.0.pom'.
               > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.36.209]
 failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordapp:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins
/cordapp/3.1.0/cordapp-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins/cord
app/3.1.0/cordapp-3.1.0.pom'.
               > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168
.243.150] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordformation:3.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordformation:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/corda/plug
ins/cordformation/3.1.0/cordformation-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/corda/plugins/c
ordformation/3.1.0/cordformation-3.1.0.pom'.
               > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.36.209]
 failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordformation:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins
/cordformation/3.1.0/cordformation-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins/cord
formation/3.1.0/cordformation-3.1.0.pom'.
               > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168
.243.150] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:3.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/corda/plug
ins/quasar-utils/3.1.0/quasar-utils-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/corda/plugins/q
uasar-utils/3.1.0/quasar-utils-3.1.0.pom'.
               > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.36.209]
 failed: Connection refused: connect
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins
/quasar-utils/3.1.0/quasar-utils-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins/quas
ar-utils/3.1.0/quasar-utils-3.1.0.pom'.
               > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168
.243.150] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

---

Comment: looks like a connection problem: do you have a proxy? Have you configured it?

Comment: yes @Leviand , i am working under my organizations proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need access to Maven to download the required Corda and CorDapp dependencies.